# nopCommerce 3.2 / Email fails to send / Configuration issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, email, azure, nopcommerce

I'm attempting to get email setup on nopCommerce 3.2.  I'm having some kind of issue relating to the "Keep Alive" service.  I'm using rackspace for the email and believe I've got it configured just fine using SSL and port 465.  This error is occurring both on my local machine with localhost and on a Windows Azure virtual machine.

Here is the error I'm getting in the nopCommerce log file.

```
> Short Message:
> 
> Error while running the 'Keep alive' schedule task. Unable to connect
> to the remote server


> Full message:
> 
> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:15536 at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
> SocketAddress socketAddress) at
> System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
> Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
> ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
> exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest&
> request) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) at
> Nop.Services.Common.KeepAliveTask.Execute() in KeepAliveTask.cs:line
> 27 at Nop.Services.Tasks.Task.Execute(Boolean throwException) in
> Task.cs:line
> 83
```

I've read several posts on the subject but can't find anything that actually discusses how to solve this.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I just noticed that the 127.0.0.1:15536 IP is showing up on both machines.  This is the assigned address by Visual Studio for this project on the localhost, but on both my local machine and on the Azure VM, it's using a diff domain.  Anyone with nopCom or gen .NET knowledge know why or from where it's pulling this URL?

Answer (score 0):

The keepalive url is retrieved from the StoreUrl value on Configuration -> General Settings but there is no connection between the keepalive task and the mail services.
This keepalive task simply pings the application so IIS does not stop it.

If your mail service is not working check the System -> Message Queue, try to send a new test mail from the email configuration and check again the logs.